# Is there a way to store loop outputs into a list in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I am trying to take the output of a loop in R and trying to store it into a list, however, I seem to only be able to store the last value of the loop for some reason and not all of the values generated from the loop.  Here is my code so far:

```
y <- list(x)
for (i in 1:10) {
x <- rnorm(2,0,1)
y <- x
```

Answer (score 1):

or this...

```
y <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  y <- c(y, rnorm(2,0,1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below is the thing you are after

```
y <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  y[[length(y)+1]] <- rnorm(2,0,1)
}
```

or

```
y <- replicate(10,rnorm(2,0,1),simplify = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler `for`

```
   y <- list()
      for (i in 1:10){
            y[[i]] <- rnorm(2,0,1)
      }
```

There's also the single line using `lapply`

```
y <- lapply(1:10, rnorm(2, 0, 1))
```